# Is there a keyboard shortcut for the "select element" functionality in Webkit Web Inspector?

Tags: google-chrome, safari, webkit, web-inspector

You know, the button that you click so you can click on an element to focus it in the DOM inspector. It is likely if such a shortcut exists on both Safari and Chrome that it might be different between them, but I'm really tired of hunting that button down all the time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both Chrome and the nightly build of Webkit use the keyboard shortcut

`Command + Shift + C`

Comment: This is sweet. Thanks! Now Safari needs to follow suit, so I can do something similar for ios debugging.

Comment: For Safari you can use `Command + Shift + I` to open the inspector, but you still have to click the Inspect button on the panel before you can select an element.